# Making Haskell functions point-free

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I'm a Haskell beginner and I've been playing around with point-free functions. I have problems with two functions - lambdabot's solutions were absolutely unreadable and made the code obfuscated, so I'm asking here in case there is a way to simplify the functions.

The first function removes duplicates from a list.

```
func1 :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
func1 [] = []
func1 (x:xs) = x : (func1 . filter (/=x) $ xs)
```

I tried making a point-free version of this function with `foldr` and `>>=` but did not succeed.

The second function maps a list to a list of tuples containing the original elements and how often they occurred in the list.

```
func2 :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
func2 xs = map ( \f -> (f, count f xs) ) xs
```

where `count a = length.filter(==a)`. I am not sure if making a point-free version of this function while maintaining readability is even possible, but I'd like to make sure.

Any help with making the two functions point-free will be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, `func1` can be written as a fold: `func1 = foldr (\x xs -> x : filter (/= x) xs) []`.<sup>1</sup> However, you don't have to, as it's identical to the standard function [`nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3anub).

And you can remove some points from `func2` using the `(&&&) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b,c)`<sup>2</sup> combinator from [`Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html):

```
func2 xs = map (id &&& (`count` xs)) xs
```

Which can then be made fully point-free:

```
func2 = (id &&&) . flip count >>= map
```

But, frankly, I had to use lambdabot to do that last step; I'd suggest keeping that function in its original form. Point-free style is only helpful when it aids comprehension; if you're having difficulty making a function point-free, then it's probably counterproductive.

<sup>1</sup> Which can then be made fully point-free as `foldr (liftM2 (.) (:) (filter . (/=))) []` (thanks again, lambdabot!) but, again, I really don't recommend this. There's not a point-free combinator for *every* situation.

<sup>2</sup> `(&&&)` actually has a more general type; it works with any `Arrow`, rather than just `(->)`. But that's not relevant here.